# VIM automatically changing font and encoding for CJK

Tags: vim, encoding, fonts, cjk

I was using VIM mainly for editing code. However, I want to extend its using to daily casual text reading. I need to read both Chinese and Japanese files, with CP932, CP950 and CP936 code page.

There are threads discussing about how to set guifontwide and encoding, but what I want is to automatically display different content using different fonts. For instance, a Chinese character rendered with Japanese font looks terrible, and vice versa. Also, A Chinese font library doesn't essentially contains all Japanese characters, and vice versa.

What I want is some kind of script, that sets VIM to use different encoding and font when Chinese is detected, and another set of encoding and font when Japanese is detected.

I am using GVIM 7.4 on Windows 7 64 bit US_EN version.

Any suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: I've noticed a beta vim stack exchange group ( http://vi.stackexchange.com/ ). Perhaps ask this question there?  Not sure what the SO lawyers thing about posting here and there, or even if I should have posted this message here, but it might help you.